# Como fazer barra ficar responsiva?

Tags: html, css, less

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando fazer com que os ícones desse player de vídeo HTML5 fique responsivo.

```
      <div id="video-controls">
            <div class="play-video">
                {!! Html::image('img/video/play.png', 'Play / Pause Video', ['class' => 'play-pause']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="progress">
                <span class="progress-bar"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="mute-video">
                {!! Html::image('img/video/mute.png', 'Mudo', ['class' => 'mute']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="volume">
                <span class="volume-bar"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="setting-video">
                {!! Html::image('img/video/settings.png', 'Opções', ['class' => 'settings']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="full">
                {!! Html::image('img/video/full-screen.png', 'Tela Cheia', ['class' => 'full-screen']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
```

- CSS

  ```
      .video{
          position: relative;
          width: 100%;
          max-width: 873px;
          margin: auto;

          #video-controls{
              position: absolute;
              background-color: #eff2f6;
              width: 98%;
              max-width: 850px;
              margin: auto;
              left: 0;
              right: 0;
              bottom: 3px;
              line-height: 18px;
              height: 18px;
              opacity: 1;
              text-align: center;
              transition: all 0.35s ease;
              display: table-cell;

              div{
                  display: inline-block;
                  max-width: 100%/6;
              }
          }
     }
  ```

Já usei `display: table` e `display:table-cell`, `display:inline-block`. Mas não consegui. O tamanho do barra do controle de video é de `850px`. Preciso que fique responsivo até esse tamanho apenas.

Tentei usar `width: 100%` e `max-width`, e nada.

O `main` é pai de todos, mas não tem um `css` que interfira.

Comment: Consegue fazer um [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Não vou conseguir hoje...

Comment: Quer que a tag `div#video-controls` fique responsiva certo? Onde ela está? Coloque o HTML que envolve ela na pergunta.

Comment: Ela está aí doido.

Comment: Mas ela é `100%`. Preciso que os ícones preencham todo o espaço dessa barra proporcionalmente.

Comment: "Onde ela está?" eu quis dizer a localização dela no código, quais são os elementos pais dela. Ela é filha do `body`, ou da _tag_ `video` ou de uma `div`? Coloque também o CSS desses parentes.

Comment: `main` > `div.video` > `div#video-controls`.

Comment: Já experimentou usar `display: flex;` ?

Comment: Não experimentei porquê li que essa propriedade ainda não está funcionando em todos os navegadores. Mas talvez tenha algum método que faça com que ela funcione. Vou tentar usar.

Comment: Mas em quais elementos eu aplico essa propriedade @devgaspa ?

Comment: está propriedade funciona como se fosse um contêiner para seus filhos deixando, por exemplo, todos os divs filhos do contêiner flexíveis. este artigo pode te ajudar (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: Boa tarde DeeSouza, tente sempre postar códigos gerados, você pode pegar isto com o Ctrl+U no webbrowser, se não você limita a sua ajuda que é um problema com CSS apenas a quem trabalhar com o mesmo framework (que acredito ser o Laravel). Boa sorte!